# How to rewrite these PHP OpenSSL calls in .NET Cryptography?

Tags: php, .net, openssl

We need to encrypt data for a third-party service. The service provides this sample code in PHP. The output of the sample code is two values - `$encryptedText` and `$aesKeyEncrypted`.

```php
$plainText = 'Test payload';
$privateKeyPem = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ... ';

$aesKey = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$encryptedText = openssl_encrypt($plainText, "AES-128-ECB", $aesKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKeyPem);
openssl_private_encrypt($aesKey, $aesKeyEncrypted, $privateKey);
```

However, our code is in .NET 6. How to do the same using .NET 6 Cryptography classes?

I've found that I can use `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(16)` instead of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)` but I have no idea how to implement the rest.

Comment: Kindly note that Stackoverflow is not a free code converting service. Your PHP code is a **hybrid encryption scheme** where you generate a random (16 bytes long) key for AES encryption is ECB mode. The AES is encrypted in a second step using RSA encryption. As both encryptions are often used it should be no problem in finding tons of examples.

Comment: Sure, I tried. For example - 1) Most of the samples on the web I found either used archaic APIs or APIs made obsolete in .NET 6.  2) The AES/SymmetricAlgorithm requires an Initialization Vector but there is no sign of transferring it in the PHP sample, so I doubt IV is used in the PHP version but I found no instruction how to "don't use" it.

Comment: The ECB mode is the only AES mode that does not require an IV

Comment: Thanks. I was able to match `openssl_encrypt` call in .NET 6. But I'm still failing with matching `openssl_private_encrypt` as it encrypts any data with a private key. In .NET 6, I found two candidates - `RSA.Encrypt` which uses a public key instead of a private key and `RSA.SignHash` and `SignData` which expect that the data being encrypted is a hash instead of accepting any data. As such, none of them are a match. Any hints?